# Swift - Set CollectionView corner radius

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, cornerradius

how do I set a corner radius on my UICollectionView?

Just to be clear, I actually mean the CollectionView itself, not the cells.

```
let theCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let v = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    v.backgroundColor = .white
    v.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .always

    return v
}()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all `UIView`, you can use:

```
theCollectionView.layer.cornerRadius = 10 // or whatever radius value you want
theCollectionView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: worked like a charm. Thanks. But is the second line for?

Comment: Sorry, thought that second line was required but just realized it works without.

Comment: Hi, can you please say in which func I should call this code?